# Katalon API tests, How to access response header location?

Tags: katalon-studio, web-api-testing

I need to parse this header value & pass on to next api call to get the cookies(token)
[Please see the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZxCG.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ResponseObject response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/YOUR_REQUEST'))
def parsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.getResponseText())
println parsed.get("headers").get("location")
```

You will need to import the following classes:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ResponseObject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this. I use to get another field in header

```
response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Your_API'))
Map parsed = response.getHeaderFields()
String api= parsed.Api (base on the name of api that youn return)
```